# Make react-panelgroup drag area larger

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-panelgroup (see: https://github.com/DanFessler/react-panelgroup)

The area to drag a section wider/smaller is a line. It's very narrow. I wanted to know if anyone has found a way to widen the draggable area? We have a center pane in our app. It would be nice if, instead of just* the line, we could click anywhere on the center panel and drag it in either direction.

I can't seem to find an answer. We may be using an incompatible library.